# Андроид-Студия требует преобразовать класс фрагмента в статичный, как избежать этого

Tags: java, android, классы, android-fragment

Есть класс

```
public class Report_c_day extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
```

с  вложенным классом диалогового окна, используя фрагмент:

```
public void onclick_date_view (View view)
{
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
    @Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // устанавливаем дату, которая отображается в диалоговом окне
        int yy = date_choice_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = date_choice_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = date_choice_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd)
    {
        // получаем выбранную в диалоговом окне дату и сохраняем ее
        day = dd;
        month = mm;
        year = yy;
        date_choice_calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dd);
        date_choice_calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mm);
        date_choice_calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, yy);
        // обновляем информацию в Надписи
        date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd.MM.yyyy");
        date_choice = date_format.format(date_choice_calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        date_view.setText(date_choice);
    }
}
```

Андроид подчеркивает красным имя класса SelectDateFragment и требует преобразовать его в статичный. Если преобразовать, то я не могу передать данные в него, и получить их обратно. Как подправить код, чтобы не делать класс SelectDateFragment статичным?

Вопрос можно решить, если вынести диалог во внешний класс, но появляется вопрос с данными, но для немного другой ситуации. По правилам форума вынес вопрос отдельно: Как передать/получить данные в/из диалогового фрагмента DatePicker [Как передать/получить данные в/из диалогового фрагмента DatePicker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504493/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-datepicker)

Comment: Вынесите его в отдельный файл, например... Вообще нет смысла делать диалоги внутренним классом активити.

Comment: Класс вынес. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой синтаксис обращения к переменным из бывшего внешнего класса. Создать экземпляр бывшего внешнего класса и указывать имя_класса.имя_переменной?

Comment: В случае фрагмента-диалога и активити вы можете получить вашу активити через `getActivity()` в диалоге и скастовать полученное к типу класса вашей активити. А вообще вам бы пояснить зачем вам всё это.

Comment: Без конкретного кода я пока не понимаю. Статичный код фрагмента внутри - работает, но нет доступа к его переменным, не могу ни передать данные, ни получить (не считая считывания с Надписи (тексвью) и запись туда, а также прочих "непрямых методов"). Вынесенный диалог пока тоже не могу заставить заработать. Осознаю, что не хватает понимания Контекста и взаимодействия классов, но что про это ни читал - не проясняет. Могу понять только на конкретном примере. Задача - первое приложение, стратегическая цель - сменить профессию.

Comment: Сформулировал вопрос из этой серии для другой ситуации, может он откроет дверь к понимаю контекста диалогового фрагмента: (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504465/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0)