# Доступ из диалогового фрагмента к другому классу (базе данных) - не своего Окна (Активити)

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Для введения нового пункта списка я решил использовать хваленое диалоговое окно на фрагменте. Но мне нужно проверить, не ввел ли пользователь название пункта, которое уже есть. Чтобы не гонять инфу в Окно (Активити) и в случае чего закрывать и опять открывать диалоговое окно, я хочу прямо из диалогового фрагмента отправить запрос в базу данных, которая у меня вынесена в отдельный класс (DB). На вход он требует контекст. Вот так я открываю БД в обычном Окне:

```
    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();// вызываем метод внутри класса БД по подключению
```

А в диалоговом фрагменте что ни пиши, все ему не нравится: ни this, ни getActivity(), ни даже getAplication(). В первом случае он пишет: "DB (андроид.контент.контекст) - так должно быть, а в DB не может быть применим (имя_пакета.имя _диалогового_фрагмента)". На второе - "недостижимое утверждение". Третье просто выделяет красным цветом.
Что же делать?

Answer (score 1):

Если под "Окно" вы понимаете Активити, то конструктор вашего класса по работе с БД принимает собственно `Activity` или `Context` в качестве параметра.

Таким образом во фрагменте в качестве аргумента должно подойти `getActivity()`, кое и Активити и Контекст.
И если у вас это не работает, то вы что-то делаете не так и вам надо показать код в месте ошибки.

Comment: На данный момент преобразовал фрагмент в полноценное Окно (Activity) для решения этого вопроса, поэтому кода не сохранилось. Я решил, что диалоговое окно на фрагменте - это не полноценный фрагмент, а некий упрощенный объект, который резко ограничен в связях с другими объектами, т.е. может передать только "да", "нет", "не знаю". Когда буду делать следующее диалоговое окно, попробую повторить и вернуться к вопросу. Благодарю за внимание.