# Как передать/получить данные в/из диалогового фрагмента DatePicker

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Есть диалоговый фрагмент:

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
    @Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    // устанавливаем дату, которая отображается в диалоговом окне
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(getActivity().date_choice_millis);
    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd)
    {
    // получаем выбранную в диалоговом окне дату и сохраняем ее
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dd);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mm);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, yy);
    getActivity().date_choice_millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

И несколько Окон (Activity), обращающихся к нему. В каждом Окне есть метод, вызывающий диалоговый фрагмент:

```
public void onclick_date_view (View view)
{
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

    действия после выбора новой даты ...// Возможно, действия после обновления должны происходить в другом месте?
}
```

Конструкция getActivity().date_choice_millis (переменная из вызвавшего класса) не работает. Как получить и передать данные из/в вызвавшее Окно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пример из моего проекта - передача из фрагмента в `DatePicker` и возврат результата в фрагмент. Способ корректно переносит повороты устройства и тп. бедствия:

**UPD**: в связи с исключением метода `getCalendarView()` из Material-стиля календаря переписал получение введенной даты из переданных в колбэк параметров

Класс Date Picker:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Long mDate = getArguments().getLong("date");
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(mDate);
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        Calendar с = Calendar.getInstance();
        с.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
        long date = c.getTimeInMillis();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra ("date" , date);
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode() , Activity.RESULT_OK , i);

    }
}
```

Часть фрагмента, в котором по нажатию на поле `TextView` (vDate) появляется Date Picker, получение результата, а так же вывод полученной даты в поле `TextView`, по которому кликали:

```
public class EditTransactionFragment extends Fragment {



    private final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    private TextView vDate;
    private final int CHANGE_DATE = 2;
    Transaction mTransaction;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);
        if (mTransaction == null) mTransaction = new Transaction();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        long mDate;

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_transaction, null);

        mDate = mTransaction.getDate();
        vDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tr_date);
        vDate.setOnClickListener(new DateClickListener(mDate));
        setTextDate(mDate);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (data == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case CHANGE_DATE:
                Long date = data.getLongExtra("date", 0);
                mTransaction.setDate(date);
                setTextDate(date);
                return;
        }
    }

    private void setTextDate(Long date) {
        vDate.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
    }


    private class DateClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private long mDate;

        public DateClickListener(long date) {
            mDate = date;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment changeDate = new DatePickerFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
            args.putLong("date", mDate);
            changeDate.setArguments(args);
            changeDate.setTargetFragment(EditTransactionFragment.this, CHANGE_DATE);
            changeDate.show(getFragmentManager(), "changeDate");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если будут нужны комментарии к коду, позже добавлю, у меня сейчас завал на работе :(

Comment: Благодарствую! Комментариев не надо, идея понятна: туда данные отправляются в Bundle args, обратно через Intent i, и onActivityResult. Непонятна только единица в new Bundle: Bundle args = new Bundle(1); Если в скобках ничего не указывать, это как то будет играть роль при обращении к DatePickerFragment с разных Окон/фрагментов?

Comment: @St-st Bundle(1) значит просто , что размер бандла ограничен одним элементом - это не влияет ни на что, кроме того, что туда можно поместить только один аргумент для сохранения. Можно конечно не указывать этот параметр и использовать конструктор по умолчанию Bundle()

Comment: @pavlofff а есть какое-то преимущество указывать кол-во параметров у бандлов ? т.е. не просто конструктор () постоянно использовать, а (2) или (6)..

Comment: @researcher Здесь те же причины, что и указывать `capacity` для коллекций (в `Bundle` создается `ArrayMap` для хранения помещенных аргументов) - экономия памяти в данном случае (дефолтное `capacity` = 10 элементов) и увеличение производительности при добавлении аргументов, при фиксированном `capacity`, когда добавляется новый элемент не происходит создание новой коллекции (при более 10 аргументов)

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а есть альтернатива методу getCalendarView()? Туториал говорит, что он устарел на 24.

Comment: @Александр Да, в Material-стиле календаря этот метод исключен. Переписал на получение  даты из переданных в колбэк параметров.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо.