# Как при нажатии на кнопку открыть DataPicker?

Tags: java, android

А также как при выборе даты забить её в EditText? Может есть какие-либо методы? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: вы не знаете, как выполнить произвольный код по нажатию на кнопку, как показать DatePicker, как получить результат выбора даты, или же, как вставить текст в EditText?

Comment: И все таки, открыть `DatePicker` или "забить" в `EditText` и почему именно  в `EditText`, если для ввода используется диалоговое окно? Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345)/ Здесь используется `TextView`. Вы можете использовать стиль от `EditText` (или `Spinner`), чтобы он выглядел, как поле ввода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из [примера](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/118-urok-59-dialogi-datepickerdialog.html) DatePickerDialog:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onclick"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textSize="22sp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  int DIALOG_DATE = 1;
  int myYear = 2011;
  int myMonth = 02;
  int myDay = 03;
  TextView tvDate;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    }

    public void onclick(View view) {
      showDialog(DIALOG_DATE);
    }


    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
      if (id == DIALOG_DATE) {
        DatePickerDialog tpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, myYear, myMonth, myDay);
        return tpd;
      }
      return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }

    OnDateSetListener myCallBack = new OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
      myYear = year;
      myMonth = monthOfYear;
      myDay = dayOfMonth;
      tvDate.setText("Today is " + myDay + "/" + myMonth + "/" + myYear);
    }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать MaterialDateAndTimePicker. 
В gradle-файле устанавливаем зависимость `compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.5.4'`

Вызываем этот метод:

```
private void showDatePickerDialog(final EditText yourEditText) {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        String month = String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1);
                        String day = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                        month = addZeroIfNeed(month);
                        day = addZeroIfNeed(day);
                        yourEditText.setText(day + "." + (month) + "." + year);//здесь в Ваш editText вставляйте
                    }
                },
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );
        dpd.show(self.getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
    }

    private String addZeroIfNeed(String string) {

        if (string.length() == 1)
            string = "0" + string;

        return string;
    }
```

Comment: Не подскажите, что в строчке ' dpd.show(self.getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog"); ' выполняет ' self '.

Comment: если вы используете фрагменты то getActivity()

Comment: self указывает на context данной activity