# Как создать TimePicker в Fragment

Tags: java, android

Как создать TimePicker при нажатии на кнопку в Fragment ?

Comment: [Стоковая реализация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345) (без сторонних библиотек) . Речь идет о `DatePicker`, но разница минимальна.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего - поискать на GitHub библиотеку и использовать её. Например эту - [SlideDateTimePicker](https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker)

1. Скачиваем либу
2. Помещаем папку с ней в корень проекта
3. Подключаем в либу к проекту в gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
}
```

4. Создаём слушатель

```
SlideDateTimeListener listener = new SlideDateTimeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateTimeSet(Date date)
    {
        // Do something with the date. This Date object contains
        // the date and time that the user has selected.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateTimeCancel()
    {
        // Overriding onDateTimeCancel() is optional.
    }
};
```

5. Показываем диалог

```
new SlideDateTimePicker.Builder(getSupportFragmentManager())
    .setListener(listener)
    .setInitialDate(new Date())
    .build()
    .show();
```

---

Лично мне больше нравится вот эта либа: [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

Comment: при вызове пикера из фрагмента есть нюансы (смотрите мой ответ на аналогичный вопрос в комментарии под вопросом), так же в вопросе есть некая кнопка ..

Comment: @pavlofff, прочитал ответ, но про нюансы не нашёл(

Comment: Со стандартной реализацией пикеров есть проблема - они на разных версиях ОС выглядят по разному. И если это увидит дизайнер - он будет в ярости)

Comment: Юрий, я был бы вам признателен, если бы вы помогли мне создать TimePicker и написали манул, по вашей либе MaterialDateTimePicker

Тут ключевой момент идет, что я вызываю TimePicker из Framgment

Comment: @MartinezToni, нет разницы откуда вызывать. Что именно у вас не получается? В описании либы есть мануал и там же есть приложение-пример