# методы DatePickerDialog для двух дат

Tags: android, datepicker, inner

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть необходимость использовать методы для выбора даты в DatePickerDialog для двух дат. Есть следующий код:

```
    public void setDate(View v, Calendar dateSelected) {
    //отображаем диалоговое окно для выбора даты
    new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), datePickerDialogListener(dateSelected),
            dateToDay.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            dateToDay.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            dateToDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            .show();
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerDialogListener(Calendar dateSelected) {
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            dateSelected.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            dateSelected.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            dateSelected.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        }
    };
    return d;
}
```

Данные методы будут вызываться в следующем коде:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.first_date_selected:
            setDate(v, firstDateSelected);
            break;
        case R.id.last_date_selected:
            setDate(v, lastDateSelected);
            break;
        case R.id.button_view:

            break;

    }

}
```

Но, метод DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener не работает, т.к. нужно объявлять передаваемый параметр статическим, а мне нужно сетить в него значения.
Как можно сделать, что бы данный метод позволял работать с параметром.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы хотите. Листенеры возвращают данные, а не принимают. Что и зачем вы хотите туда сеттить.

Comment: Пользователь будет выбирать дату начала периода и дату конца периода, мне нужно, что бы код работал для обоих периодов и даты, которые были выбраны пользователями сетелись в соответствующие переменные.

Comment: Ну а причем листенер, он возвращает введенные в пикере даты, а не принимает их/ посмотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345), может он будет вам полезен.

Comment: Да, это именно то, что нужно. Как Вам плюс в карму поставить?

Comment: Ну проголосуйте за тот ответ. Если тот ответ полностью решает вашу проблему, я тогда закрою этот вопрос, как дубликат того?

Comment: Проголосовал. Этот можно закрывать как дубликат. Ещё раз большое Вам спасибо.