# SQLite - Конвертирование из String в Sql.Date

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Необходимо сконвертировать переменную типа String, в переменную типа Sql.Date.
Есть метод добавления данных в таблицу и нужно сконвертировать тип переменной:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
void addAccount(String name, String city, String editTextDateParam) {
    try (SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase()) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("name", name);
        cv.put("birthday", editTextDateParam);
        cv.put("city", city);
        db.insert("Users", null, cv);
        dbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Метод получения данных в переменную String из Datepicker'a:

```
public void callDatePicker(View view) {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    editTextDateParam = dayOfMonth + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year;
                    datePick.setText(editTextDateParam);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Удобнее работать с Linux Timestamp (количество миллисекунд с какой то там даты), а не SQL.Date. Его удобнее конвертировать в различные форматы вывода, удобнее хранить, сортировать и обрабатывать. В [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345), как получить такую дату и сконвертировать из `EditText`. Сохраняется как обычное число. String для обработки дат вовсе не подходящий формат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite не поддерживает формат `date/datetime` - [пруфлинк](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), зачем вам в этом случае переводить `String` в `SQL.Date`? 
Принятым в SQLite форматом даты является текстовое поле в виде `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`

Форматируйте вашу дату в этот формат с помощью [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) и все.