# Не запускается DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, dialogfragment, android-dialog, datepicker

Есть DatePickerFragment:

```
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

    }
}
```

Есть диалог, в котром есть текстовое поле, из которого должен вызываться DatePickerFragment:

```
    public class AddingTaskDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String DIALOG_TASK_DATE = "DialogDate";
    private static final int REQUEST_TASK_DATE = 0;

    private AddingTaskListener addingTaskListener;

    public interface AddingTaskListener {
        void onTaskAdding();

        void onTaskAddingCancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            addingTaskListener = (AddingTaskListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement AddingTaskListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_task, null);

        final TextInputLayout tilTitle = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskTitle);
        final EditText etTitle = tilTitle.getEditText();

        final TextInputLayout tilDate = (TextInputLayout) container.findViewById(R.id.tilDialogTaskTitleDate);
        final EditText etDate = tilDate.getEditText();

        final Spinner taskSpinner = (Spinner) container.findViewById(R.id.dialog_task_responsible_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.person, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        taskSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        tilTitle.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_task_title));
        tilDate.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_task_date));

        builder.setView(container);

        etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (etDate.length() == 0) {
                    etDate.setText(" ");
                }

                DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                        Calendar dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        dateCalendar.set(year, month, day);
                        etDate.setText(Utils.getDate(dateCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        etDate.setText(null);
                    }
                };
                datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePickerFragment");
            }

        });
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                addingTaskListener.onTaskAdding();
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                addingTaskListener.onTaskAddingCancel();
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });


        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                final Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                if (etTitle.length() == 0) {
                    positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                    tilTitle.setError(getResources().getText(R.string.dialog_error_empty_title));
                }
                etTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
                            positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                            tilTitle.setError(getResources().getText(R.string.dialog_error_empty_title));
                        } else {
                            positiveButton.setEnabled(true);
                            tilTitle.setErrorEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return alertDialog;
    }
}
```

Сам AddingTaskDialog вызывается из Activity.
Проблема в том, что при нажатии на **etDate** возникает ошибка, в чем может быть дело?

Вот, что выдает:

```
04-08 17:34:09.833 2987-2987/com.mn.nikolay.prototype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.mn.nikolay.prototype, PID: 2987
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment null must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:384)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:363)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:142)
                                                                        at com.mn.nikolay.prototype.dialogs.AddingTaskDialog$1.onClick(AddingTaskDialog.java:110)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: какая именно ошибка? Посмотрите так же [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345)

Comment: Просто приложение вылетает

Comment: В логах что пишет?

Comment: Просто скопируйте сюда вывод стектрейса из logcat. Нет ошибки - нет решения