# как можно передать данные из DialogFragment в вызвавший его фрагмент и заменить отображение в TextView

Tags: android

Как можно передать данные из `DialogFragment` в вызвавший его фрагмент и заменить отображение в `TextView`. У меня есть 3 таба, каждый таб это фрагмент, все находятся в одном активити.В фрагменте есть кнопка при нажатии на которую появляется `DialogFragment` с `NumberPicker` (Минуты,секунды), так же в этом фрагменте есть `TextView` с отображение счетчиков, мне нужно изменить значение в `TextView` на выбранные минуты и секунды в `DialogFragment` (после нажатия `ОК`).С помощью интерфейса я передаю данные в `MainActivity`,но от туда не знаю как передать и корректно поменять значение `TextView`.

Код `DialogFragment`:

```
//Создаем интерфейс для передачи данных в активити
public interface DialogReverseListener {
    void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog,int minutes,int seconds);

    void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);

}


//подписаться на действия интерфейса
DialogReverseListener mListener;


NumberPicker numberPickerMinutes;
NumberPicker numberPickerSeconds;

SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

int pickedMinutes = 0;
int pickedSeconds = 0;

TextView textMinutes, textSeconds, textSplash;

public DialogReverseFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

//Переопределяем что б был доступ к Интерфейсу
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (DialogReverseListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() +
                "must implements DialogReverseListener");
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Выберите время");

    //Через фрагмент находим переференсе
    preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preferences.edit();

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_reverse, null);

    numberPickerMinutes = (NumberPicker) contentView.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMinutes);
    numberPickerSeconds = (NumberPicker) contentView.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerSeconds);
    numberPickerMinutes.setMaxValue(60);
    numberPickerMinutes.setMinValue(0);
    numberPickerSeconds.setMaxValue(60);
    numberPickerSeconds.setMinValue(0);


    textMinutes = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.textViewReverseMinutes);
    textSeconds = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.textViewReverseSeconds);
    textSplash = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.textViewReverseSplash);

    builder.setView(contentView);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
            mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(DialogReverseFragment.this);
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            int minutes = numberPickerMinutes.getValue();
            int seconds = numberPickerSeconds.getValue();

            mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(DialogReverseFragment.this,minutes,seconds);
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });


    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    //Смена цвета Позитив и Негатив кнопок
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
    });
    return alertDialog;
}
```

В `MainActivity` реализую интерфейс:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    DialogReverseFragment.DialogReverseListener

public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog,int minutes,int seconds) {

 @Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog,int minutes,int seconds) {

    //Как отсюда передать данные обратно в фрагмент и заменить вид TextView

}
```

Как перерисовать `TextView` на данные которые я получил с диалога (изначальное значение `00:00`)

Comment: возможно [аналогичный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345) с `DatePicker` вам поможет.

Comment: так же для ввода времени рекомендуется использовать виджет `TimePicker`, а не несколько `NumberPicker`, так как он предоставляет более удобный интерфейс для возврата введенного  времени

Comment: Понимаете у меня аналог секундомера , мне время не надо , а значение минуты и секунд для отчета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать метод setTargetFragment - тогда результат будет возвращаться именно в тот фрагмент, в который Вам нужно ;)
Пример вызова диалога из фрагмента:

```
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = ShopSignFragmentDialog.newInstance();
    dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, REQUEST_CODE_SHOP_SIGN);
    dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "ShopSignFragmentDialog");
```

В диалоге, который мы вызываем и который наследуется от DialogFragment для передачи результата используем метод

```
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

После чего, обрабатываем результат в вызывающем фрагменте в методе onActivityResult.
Пример:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SHOP_SIGN) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //do something
        }
    } else
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь,ваш совет сработал идеально,а для тех у кого буду подобные возникать проблемы вот хорошая статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/259805/