# Получить дату из DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android

Есть класс `DialogObject` наследник от `DialogFragment`:

```
public class DialogObject extends DialogFragment{
    private TextView tvDate;
    private DatePickerFragment newFragment;

    public static DialogObject newInstance(String title, String date) {
        DialogObject dialogObject = new DialogObject();
        dialogObject.setCancelable(false);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putString("date", date);
        dialogObject.setArguments(args);
        return dialogObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        String date = getArguments().getString("date");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(title);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_object, null);
        tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        tvDate.setText(date);
        tvDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

из которого вызывается `DatePickerFragment`:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    }
}
```

Вопрос, как при нажатии кнопки `ок` в классе `DatePickerFragment`, в классе `DialogObject` назначить `TextView tvDate` выбранную дату?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

Пример реализации можете посмотреть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/8544322

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!