# передать в DatePickerDialog дату с TextView

Tags: java, android

Есть `TextView` с датой, при нажатии на `TextView` открывается диалог `DatePickerDialog`. Как сделать так, что-бы в открывшемся диалоге `DatePickerDialog` показывалась дата из `TextView`?

диалог отрывается так:

```
// вызываем диалог DatePicker
        tvDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogDatePicker newFragment = new DialogDatePicker();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });
```

сам класс DatePickerDialog:

```
public class DialogDatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("отправляем дату по назначению");
        intent.putExtra("message", checkDigit(dayOfMonth) + "." + checkDigit(month + 1) + "." + year);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    // добавляет ноль перед цифрой, если она одна
    public String checkDigit(int number) {
        return number <= 9 ? "0" + number : String.valueOf(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Взять дату-строку, распарсить и установить в DatePickerDialog

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345

Comment: @pavlofff находил это раньше но до конца не вник, сейчас более внимательно посмотрел, то что нужно. Сделайте это ответом. Спасибо!