# Передать данные из Activity в Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

В моей приложении на Андроид я использую NavigationView. 
Для перехода по пунктам меню Drawer'a использую такой код в главной активности:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Создадим новый фрагмент
    //Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_calendar) {
        // Handle the calendar action
        fragmentClass = CalendarFragment.class;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_events) {
        fragmentClass = EventsFragment.class;

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Вставляем фрагмент, заменяя текущий фрагмент
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    // Выделяем выбранный пункт меню в шторке
    item.setChecked(true);
    // Выводим выбранный пункт в заголовке
    setTitle(item.getTitle());

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

При переходе по пунктам меню открываются соответствующие фрагменты. В фрагменте EventsFragment есть кнопка, при нажатии которой открывается DialogFragment, из которого я получаю данные (название,дату и время). При закрытии этого диалога кнопкой "ОК" через "листенера" данные передаются в главную активити.

Я хочу передать эти полученные данные из этой активности во фрагмент EventsFragment. Я так понимаю, что передать данные я могу через ссылку на фрагмент. Как мне ее получить, если фрагменты определяются через меню? Или может быть можно передать данные напрямую из одного фрагмента в другой?

Теперь (руководствуясь советами) делаю так:
Вызывающий фрагмент:

```
public class EventsFragment extends Fragment {
final static int REQUEST_CODE_EVENT = 1;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_events, container, false);
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab_events);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment addingEventDialogFragment = new AddingEventDialogFragment();
            addingEventDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(EventsFragment.this, REQUEST_CODE_EVENT);
            addingEventDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "AddingEventDialogFragment");
        }
    });
    return v;
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EVENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String eventTitle = (String) data.getStringExtra(AddingEventDialogFragment.EVENT_KEY);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Event is added. Title is " + eventTitle , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //currentEventFragment.addEvent(event);
    }
}
}
```

Вызываемый фрагмент:

```
public class AddingEventDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
final static String EVENT_KEY = "EVENT_KEY";
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_add_event, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            event.setTitle(etEventTitle.getText().toString());
            if (etEventDate.length() != 0 || etEventTime.length() != 0) {
                event.setDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            }
            addingEventListener.onEventAdded(event);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EventsFragment.class);
            intent.putExtra(EVENT_KEY, event.getTitle());
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            dialogInterface.dismiss();

        }
    }); 
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    return alertDialog;
}
}
```

Так у меня получается передать String (или int) через getStringExra(). Но как мне передавать просто Serializible объекты? Если получать так (привожу ниже), то я ничего не получаю. Что я должен написать у вызываемого объекта?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EVENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        String eventTitle = (String) bundle.get(AddingEventDialogFragment.EVENT_KEY);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Event is added. Title is " + eventTitle , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот вопрос задан и на него уже дан ответ несколько раз. Попробуйте использовать поиск или просто обратите внимание на вопросы похожие на ваш справа в колонке "Похожие"

Comment: Кажется, ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/733295/17609)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я попытался сделать, как вы предлагаете. Получить String мне удалось, а как передавать и получать другие Serializible? (я добавил изменения в вопрос, добавив то, что сейчас сделал.)

Comment: C serializable всё также как с остальным. Просто у вас данные должны быть в `Intent data` параметре метода `onActivityResult` а не в Intent активити как у вас в коде

Answer (score -1):

Вариантов огромное множество

1. Чтобы получить ссылку на фрагмент можно просто хранить в активити эту самую ссылку на фрагмент.
   Например, насколько я вижу она уже есть, так как `fragment` в данном случае является полем класса `Activity`.

   ```
   fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
   ```

Ничто не мешает проверить является ли `fragment` инстансом `EventsFragment` и отослать нужные данные. В крайнем случае можно специально в активити хранить ссылку на `EventsFragment`.

2. Передачу данных из фрагмента во фрагмент вполне несложно организовать. Сделать это можно через [`EventBus`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) если нет особых требований к тестируемости или чистоте кода и нужно все запилить быстро.
   Из вариантов чуть получше - [`RxRelay`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay), годится если используется `RxJava`.