# Передача данных из DialogFragment в Activity

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment, android-dialog

Появилась необходимость в текстовое окно установить дату. метод `showDialog(DIALOG_DATE)`  уже устарел. Предлагается использовать DialogFragment.

Ну создал на основе ДиалогФрагмента. А как же мне передать данные в активити?

пробую getActivity , нахожу текстовое поле , но метода setText не нахожу.

Как передать в диалог помню:

```
DatePickerFragment.setArguments(bundle);
DatePickerFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Fragment");
```

.

```
 public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    final Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance(); // Дата для установки нижнего порога в TimePiker
    calendar1.set(1999, 0, 1); // http://fixer.io/ хранит курсы валют начиная с 1999 года

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    DatePicker dp = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
    dp.setMinDate(calendar1.getTimeInMillis()); // ставим нижний диапазон в DatePiker
    dp.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()); // верхний диапазон   в DatePiker устанавливаем сегодняшним днем

    return datePickerDialog;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

}
```

}

Comment: Единственный способ - использовать интерфейс ?

Comment: единственный правильный способ. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Ну я так и сделал. Хотел бы способы с меньшим количеством кода увидеть.

Comment: Это не тот случай, где стоит экономить на строках кода. Почитайте про IoC. Тогда это станет не просто "делай так", а "вот для чего".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать в активити public метод и передавать туда.

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).sendData(dateBegin,duration,durationPeriod);
```