# вопрос по DatePiсker , при открытии пикера показывается не установленная дата

Tags: java, android

1) При клике на датапикер  для выбора всплывает диалог в котором дата стоит текущая, а не установленная в `TextView`. Метода в документации что-то не нашел. Поясняю: выбираю 2000 год, всё отобразилось, кликаю еще раз и хочу чтобы отталкиваться пришлось от 2000 года , а не снова 2017. Это нужно для удобства, когда я кликаю подряд по определенным годам и получаю результаты по сети.

Сделан на основе диалогфрагмент. В активити результат отправляю через калбек.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

DialogFragmentListener mCallback;
Boolean timesCalled = true; // Используется как костыль.   при нажатии на DataPiker он вызывается дважды.

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    final Calendar calendarMin = Calendar.getInstance(); // Дата для установки нижнего порога в DataPiker
    calendarMin.set(1999, 0, 1); // http://fixer.io/ хранит курсы валют начиная с 1999 года . Отсчет месяцев идет с нуля.

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    DatePicker dp = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
    dp.setMinDate(calendarMin.getTimeInMillis()); // ставим нижний диапазон в DatePiker
    dp.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()); // верхний диапазон   в DatePiker устанавливаем сегодняшним днем


    return datePickerDialog;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    if (timesCalled == true) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, day);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        mCallback.getDate(formattedDate);

        timesCalled = false;
    }

}


interface DialogFragmentListener {  //узнать зачем нужен вложенный интерфейс
    void getDate(String date);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mCallback = (DialogFragmentListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement DialogFragmentListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        timesCalled = true;   // возвращаем исходное значение
        mCallback = null;
    }


}
```

Метод, принимающий калбек в активити

```
public void getDate(String date) {
        Current_Date.setText(date);
    }
```

Comment: Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345) - полностью рабочее решение. Вопрос должен содержать только одну проблему. Если у вас несколько проблем, задайте несколько вопросов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По первому все правильно, вы ведь получатете текущую дату и передаете её **year, month, day** в эту функцию

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
```

Вам нужно получить из поля установленное значение и распарсить его, например так

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

String getgatestr = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
if(! getgatestr.isEmpty()){
    String[] arrdate = getgatestr.split("\\.");
    day = Integer.parseInt(arrdate[0]);
    month = Integer.parseInt(arrdate[1])-1;
    year = Integer.parseInt(arrdate[2]);
}
```

По второму вопросу, во первых напишите дату выполнения этого кода, чтобы понимать от какого числа делать рассчеты, ведь в разные дни запуска будут эти ваши 2 и 3 декабря уже другими днями. А вообще в onDateSet делайте вывод в лог тех данных которые получила функция, месяц возможно не тот выводится, не от нуля, надо делать вывод в лог.

Comment: не стоит поощрять нарушать правила данного ресурса и отвечать на несколько проблем в одном вопросе. Автор оформит второй вопрос и вы сможете на него ответить. Дело в том, что это не форум, а Q&A, цель которого не помочь конкретному человеку, а создать базу решений проблем. И несколько проблем и ответов на них в одном вопросе усложняют поиск верного решения людям с аналогичными проблемами в будущем

Comment: pavlofff Там было не решение задачи, а просто совет, чтобы при создании нового вопроса человек уточнил то что я написал.