# Получить данные из DatePicker в DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker, dialogfragment

Перерыл кучу инфы, так и не понял куда копать. В своем проекте использую DatePicker. Вот код самого DatePicker:

```
public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private String month_name;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // определяем текущую дату
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        month_name = month_date.format(c.getTime());

        // создаем DatePickerDialog и возвращаем его
        Dialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, this,
                year, month, day);
        picker.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.choose_date));

        return picker;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // добавляем кастомный текст для кнопки
        Button nButton =  ((AlertDialog) getDialog())
                .getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        nButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.ready));

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker datePicker, int year,
                          int month, int day) {

        switch(month) {
            case 0:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.january);
                break;
            case 1:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.february);
                break;
            case 2:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.march);
                break;
            case 3:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.april);
                break;
            case 4:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.may);
                break;
            case 5:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.june);
                break;
            case 6:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.july);
                break;
            case 7:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.august);
                break;
            case 8:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.september);
                break;
            case 9:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.october);
                break;
            case 10:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.november);
                break;
            case 11:
                month_name = getActivity().getString(R.string.december);
                break;
        }

        TextView tv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonDate);
        tv.setText(day + " " + month_name + " " + year);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int sec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        tv.setContentDescription(day
                + "-"
                + (month+1)
                + "-"
                + year
                + " "
                + (hour + 3)
                + ":"
                + min
                + ":"
                + sec);
    }
}
```

Когда вызываю из активности, то все нормально. Я получаю данные в R.id.buttonDate. Тут вопросов нет. А вот в другой активности, у меня сначала вызывается DialogFragment и уже из него вызываю DatePicker. И тут торможу, не могу передать в DialogFragment дату. Ругается, что не может найти R.id.buttonDate. Вроде бы и сам понимаю, что фрагмент это не активити, а вот решения не могу найти.

Вот как вызываю DatePicker из фрагмента:

```
public class DialogAdditionFieldType extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView dateView;
    private DatePickerDialog datePicker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialogFragmentStyle);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
…………...

                    View buttonDateView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_date,null);
                    dateView = buttonDateView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDate);
                    ImageButton buttonDate = buttonDateView.findViewById(R.id.buttonD);

                    dateView.setText(currDateTextView);
                    // определяем текущую дату
                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    dateView.setContentDescription(day + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + year);

                    buttonDate.setOnClickListener(ClickListenerDate);

…………...

        return v;
    }

private View.OnClickListener ClickListenerDate = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment dateDialog = new DatePickerAddField();
            dateDialog.show(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    };

}
```

Уже и через Intent пытался передавать и слушателя пытался вешать. Видимо, что-то делаю не так. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345

Comment: именно про это я и писал, что данный пример то же видел. и не выходит каменный цветок.....

Comment: то есть проблема у вас в том, что dateView = null, после инфлейта не находит виджет на разметке? Тогда его там действительно нет, проверьте разметку, соответствие id на разметке и который ищите

Comment: да, в разметке его нет. во фрагменте я отдельно подключаю xml, как вы можете видеть.

Comment: в этом R.layout.button_date.xml, который вы инфлейтите и должен быть виджет с точно таким же id (R.id.buttonDate),  что вы пытаетесь позже найти. если вы получаете ошибку, что не может его найти, то его там и нет. так же приложите к вопросу сам стектрейс ошибки.