# DatePicker DialogFragment Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь создать DialogFragment c DatePickerFragment

```
class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment() {
private var listener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener? = null

private var year: Int = 0
private var month: Int = 0
private var dayOfMonth: Int = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    retrieveArguments()
}

private fun retrieveArguments() {
    val args = arguments
    if (args != null) {
        year = args.getInt(ARGUMENT_YEAR)
        month = args.getInt(ARGUMENT_MONTH)
        dayOfMonth = args.getInt(ARGUMENT_DAY)
    }
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return DatePickerDialog(context, this.listener, this.year, this.month, this.dayOfMonth)
}

fun setListener(listener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) {
    this.listener = listener
}

companion object {

    private val ARGUMENT_YEAR = "ARGUMENT_YEAR"
    private val ARGUMENT_MONTH = "ARGUMENT_MONTH"
    private val ARGUMENT_DAY = "ARGUMENT_DAY"

    fun newInstance(year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int): DatePickerFragment {
        val df = DatePickerFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putInt(ARGUMENT_YEAR, year)
        args.putInt(ARGUMENT_MONTH, month)
        args.putInt(ARGUMENT_DAY, dayOfMonth)
        df.arguments = args
        return df
    }
}
```

}

Fragment вызова:

```
class AddScheduleFragment : Fragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    override fun onDateSet(p0: DatePicker?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        et_date_start_lessons.setText(p3.toString())
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_add_schedule, container, false)


//        val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
//
        fragmentLayout.et_date_start_lessons.setOnClickListener{
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()
            val datePicker = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(
                c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            )
            datePicker.setListener(this)
            datePicker.show(childFragmentManager, null)

        }
        return fragmentLayout
    }
}
```

Но я не могу вызвать конструктор DatePickerDialog, передавал и context и activity и fragmentManager, пишет что передается Context?, Activity? или fragmentManager.

Comment: а чем инициализирована эта ваша переменная context. в вашем коде нет никаких попыток присвоить ей "живой" контекст. и зачем вторым параметром вы передаете this? какая цель этого действия?

Comment: @pavlofff, мне нужен dialogFragment, который бы содержал Calendar, и возвращал во Fragment, откуда вызвали  дату. Как это можно сделать? С учетом ViewModel

Comment: @pavlofff это внутренний код, для получения context, который может быть Null

Comment: @pavlofff обновил код. Как я понял, мне необходимо во Fragment реализовать интерфейс DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener и уже с данными что-то делать. Если я использую ViewModel, то мне нужно ведь через нее как-то добавлять данные, напрямую в EditText вроде нежелательно.

Comment: @pavlofff как сделать так, чтобы интерфейс засунуть в сам dialogFragment, а в месте вызова dialogFragment я получал саму дату.

Просто мест, где будет использовать Calendar будет несколько, не хочу в каждом реализовывать DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, так как он по сути должен просто возвращать дату и я думаю его можно засунуть в DialogFragment

Comment: где и какое значение получает переменная context из вашего кода я так и не понял. смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345) по организации DatePickerDialog в фрагменте, может он вам поможет чем то ..

Comment: @pavlofff ну а как я вам покажу что такое context, это же get-Свойство у фрагмента в kotlin.
Вот исходный код Nullable
    public Context getContext() {
        return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
    }
Хотел спросить, а что за класс у вас такой Transaction?

Comment: а, понятно тогда. В фрагменте контекст возвращает метод getActivity(), метод getContext() доступен только с API23. Transaction - это просто POJO-объект с информацией о транзакции, одно из полей которого дата (транзакции). пример из моего проекта.