# Запись даты в editText android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, мне необходимо при нажатии пользователем на editText что бы появлялся календарь и можно было выбрать дату, далее при нажатии на дату, что бы она записывалась в этот editText. Возможно ли это реализовать в android studio?
Пробовала брать чисто editText (date), но это не совсем то, что мне хочется.

Может есть возможность пойти как то через CalendarView?

Comment: добавляете editText справа от него без границ добавляете календарь, далее создать колбек события, который будет вызываться при выборе даты и в этом коллеге изменять value editText . А вообще это все гуглится и мне кажется, что вы просто не хотите этим заниматься. Код попробуйте сами написать, ничего сложного в нем нет

Comment: В андроид студии можно реализовать все.

Comment: Вот полностью [готовое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/504528/177345). Только использовать EditText тут нет надобности, так как ввод фактически не осуществляется, лучше TextView (что и используется в примере). При необходимости текствью можно стилизовать под любой виджет

Answer (score 2):

Всем спасибо большое за помощь!

Решила проблему следующим образом:

```
 private TextView mDisplayDate;
public static final String TAG = "EditActivity";
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);
    mDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edDate);
    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(EditActivity.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

В `onCreate()` добавляете слушатель нажатий в `calendarView`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 CalendarView calender;
 EditText eTxt;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 calender = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
 eTxt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

 calender.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
 int dayOfMonth) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 eTxt.setText("Date is : " + dayOfMonth +" / " + (month+1) + " / " + year);

 }
 });
 }
}
```

вот приблизительная разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.getselecteddatefromcalendaview_android_examples.com.MainActivity">

 <CalendarView
 android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="300dp"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:background="#03f0dc"

 />

 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/edittext"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView1"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
 android:text="Date not Selected" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Если же вам нужно чтобы во время открытия активности календарь был скрыт, а при нажатии на поле для ввода появлялся, то в xml нужно установить тег `android:visibility = "gone"` и добавить обработчик нажатий на поле для ввода:

```
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
            calender.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Таким образом при нажатии на поле для ввода вы будете показывать ваш календарь, а после выбора даты его можно скрыть в обработчике выбора даты: `calender.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. Вот есть [туториал](https://www.android-examples.com/get-selected-date-from-calendarview-in-android/), но вместо поля для ввода там используется обычный textView.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно на ваш edittext поставить событие, как на кнопку setOnClickListener
А в параметрах edittext желательно выключить фокус.

И использовать [данную статью](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/datepicker.php).